# FindwindowEx for outlook 2010

Tags: c++, outlook

Hi created the addin for the outlook 2007. Now addin need to support to outlook 2010 also.
But the following code fails while checking to get outlook window handle.

```
hWnd = ::FindWindowEx(*pExplorerWnd, NULL, _T("rctrl_renwnd32"), "");
```

rctrl_renwnd32 is classname for outlook 2007 whether its same for outlook 2010.?

Please clarrify it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes the classname is rctrl_renwnd32. See what happens if you specify hwndParent as NULL

Comment: Sorry again the window handle is NULL.

Comment: For the window name, don't use "". Either use _T("") if that's what you really mean or more likely you want to use NULL

Comment: it returns handle by using ::FindWindowEx(*pExplorerWnd, NULL, _T("rctrl_renwnd32"), NULL);  Thanks for this... But in UI i am creating Custom calendar view. If u get why its not retuning window handle if i use parentWnd as explorerWnd. please tell me..

Comment: Sorry I have no experience creating Add-Ins. Use Spy++ to determine whether the parent really is what you think it is.